# PHP MYSQL INNER JOIN loop and loop again

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem from looping and looping (again) on PHP MYSQL INNER JOIN

so, this is my code :

there are two tables here **product** and **stock**

each of them contain a row that had a relation = **id_product**

```
id_product // this is product table
-----------
     1
     2
     3

id_product |  stock  // this is stock table
---------------------
     1     |    2
     2     |    2
     3     |    2

$stockSum = 0;
$tommorow = mysqli_query($con, 
           "SELECT product.id_product,
                    stock.id_product,
                    stock.stock AS allstock
            FROM product INNER JOIN stock
            ON stock.id_product = product.id_product
            WHERE stock.id_product = product.id_product");

while ($dataTommorow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tommorow)) {

    $stockSum += $dataTommorow['allstock'];

    <li><?php echo $stockSum; ?> Stocks</li> // output = 2
    <li><?php echo $stockSum; ?> Stocks</li> // problem occure it's stacking -> output = 4
    <li><?php echo $stockSum; ?> Stocks</li> // (again) now become -> output = 6 
}
```

so, what i'm expected is this :

```
<li><?php echo $stockSum; ?> Stocks</li> // output = 2
<li><?php echo $stockSum; ?> Stocks</li> // output = 2
<li><?php echo $stockSum; ?> Stocks</li> // output = 2
```

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you looping through them? You should only have to run an inner join once and then the dataset returned to you should provide you with what you need. Constantly running joins over & over again on the same table with the same dataset isn't good practice nor should it be done. There might be a logic problem rather than a code problem.

Comment: You don't need the where part in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stockSum = 0; // You are casting to an integer instead cast to an array
$stockSumArray = array(); // Do this instead

while($dataTomorrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tomorrow)) {

    // You are appending data to this, so if it returned 2 on the next return 
    // it will add what ever integer was returned to the previous data that 
    // was returned. If it returns a string it will try to cast the string to 
    // an integer and add it together / add on to the existing string
    $stockSum += $dataTomorrow['allstock'];


    // !~~~ Instead Do This ~~~!

    // So instead of appending / adding the returned data together lets
    // push it to an array so we can later loop through it.
    array_push($stockSumArray, $dataTomorrow['allstock'];
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($stockSumArray); $i++) {

   // We are going to do exactly what you did before but just echo it out 
   // while looping through the array

   <li><?php echo $stockSumArray[$i]; ?> Stocks</li>
}
```

You could get a little more complicated & crazy with the above code, but this is a much more elegant solution as opposed to what you're doing above. Hope this helps, try and avoid running multiple JOINS on the same table with the same dataset, you should only have to run it once to get the data you need. Less calls, equals faster page loading, in turn equals more performant code, which in turn equals increased testability of code.